# inline assembly in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, assembly, c++-cli, inline-assembly

Why C++/CLI compiler can compile this code:

```
using namespace System;

inline void Assembly(){

__asm{
mov eax,5
}

}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

    Assembly();
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

And can NOT for this one:

```
using namespace System;


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

__asm{
mov eax,5
}
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?  Does it talk about reachability?

Comment: @BrianCain: it gave 5 errors for the second code, one of them is `Error 1 error C3644: 'main' : cannot compile the function to generate managed code`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The C++/CLI compiler supports generating both machine code and IL.  It will generate machine code for any code that is compiled without /clr in effect or functions that are bracketed with #pragma managed(push, off) and #pragma managed(pop).  Or functions that must be compiled to machine code because they contain code that cannot be translated to IL.  Like _asm, note the C4793 warning you got for the first snippet.  Suppress the warning with #pragma managed.  Such code cannot use any managed types of course.

The unit of code generation is a function.  What cannot work is a function that needs both.  Your main() function must be compiled to IL because it uses managed types.  The function won't be inlined of course.

Comment: What I wish is that I could say something like: __asm { ldc.i4.4  ... pop ... (etc.) }